# Android S/MIME development

Tags: android, cryptography, jakarta-mail

I have searched from here to the ends of the earth and have still not figured out how this is possible.

I started with using the custom built javamail/gmail api because I wanted to send the email in the background without any interaction from the user.

I then tried to build ontop of that: crypto ( http://javamail-crypto.sourceforge.net/ ) coupled with bouncycastle ( https://www.bouncycastle.org/ ) to sign the email

Because these api's are so old, they clash a lot and every time I seem to fix one obscure error, I uncover another.

I have seen 1 or 2 apps on the market that provide S/MIME encryption and have emailed the creators but have not received a reply.

Comment: Your question is missing a ... question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've officially given up, its not a case of how old the API's are but a combination of the following two problems:

There is no java.awt package in Android, but a custom andrioid.awt one. I have tried editing the jar files belonging to bouncycastle to adapt to this but to no avail.

The api's seem to not correspond with each other at all. Every time I got close to signing the email and sending it, I would find a nosuchfieldexception or nosuchmethodexception at runtime where one api was looking for something in another api.

Eventually, I just gave up trying to do it for free and found a site called Chilkat who have a perfectly working API with a 30 day trial from the first time you run the code.

Their android api's are here: [Chilkat for Android](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/chilkatAndroid.asp)

The reason I'm putting this up is for anyone else who's gone through as much blood and sweat over this as I have to know that there is some hope, even if you have to pay for it...

Comment: I'm glad you found an acceptable answer and shared it with everyone. It would have been even better if you had included more detail about your problems with Bouncycastle so that we could have documented its specific limitations *and* possibly some good workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

Djigzo S/MIME Email encryption, from the author “Djigzo”

For Blackberry devices, download the app from: http://www.djigzo.com/bb.html

Answer (score 0):

And of course it has to be free also? The APIs haven't changed because S/MIME hasn't changed. I think you'll also find the sockets API hasn't changed in eons because TCP hasn't changed. However, if you are willing to pay money, then you might consider IAIK, for example [this IAIK toolkit](http://jce.iaik.tugraz.at/sic/Products/Communication-Messaging-Security).